# Does Amazon CloudFront charges egress fees for TLS hanshake?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Establishing HTTPS connection requires about 3½KB of bandwidth for the TLS handshake, but it does not explicitly say in documentation that CloudFront charges egress fees for that.

At [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) it says:

> When a viewer makes an HTTP request that is redirected to an HTTPS request, CloudFront charges for both requests. For the HTTP request, the charge is only for the request and for the headers that CloudFront returns to the viewer. For the HTTPS request, the charge is for the request, and for the headers and the object that are returned by your origin.

Does it mean that TLS handshake data is included in the price of HTTPS request or does Amazon charge extra egress fees for TLS handshake?

Answer (score 1):

You are priced by data transfer, so the actual size of the object stored in s3. So no, you are not paying for the handshake part.

The note is just basically documenting the behaviour:
When a user connects to http, it will receive headers from CloudFront, which will lead to the browser basically doing a new request using HTTPS. So at the end you have two initial requests.